# Category layer filter issue

Tags: category

I having an issue. For some reason the attributes filter are not showed. I enable some logs and I saw this:

If I set the is anchor to **YES** this is the executed query:

```
SELECT `e`.*, `cat_index`.`position` AS `cat_index_position`, `price_index`.`price`, `price_index`.`tax_class_id`, `price_index`.`final_price`, IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL, LEAST(price_index.min_price, price_index.tier_price), price_index.min_price) AS `minimal_price`, `price_index`.`min_price`, `price_index`.`max_price`, `price_index`.`tier_price`, `at_stock_status`.`stock_status` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id=25 AND cat_index.visibility IN(2, 4) AND cat_index.category_id='86' AND cat_index.is_parent=1
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '1' AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0
 INNER JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_status` AS `at_stock_status` ON (at_stock_status.`product_id`=e.entity_id) AND (at_stock_status.stock_status = '1') AND (at_stock_status.website_id = '1') ORDER BY `price_index`.`min_price` asc, `price_index`.`min_price` asc LIMIT 8
```

if i set to **NO** this is the executed query:

```
SELECT `e`.*, `cat_index`.`position` AS `cat_index_position`, `price_index`.`price`, `price_index`.`tax_class_id`, `price_index`.`final_price`, IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL, LEAST(price_index.min_price, price_index.tier_price), price_index.min_price) AS `minimal_price`, `price_index`.`min_price`, `price_index`.`max_price`, `price_index`.`tier_price`, `at_stock_status`.`stock_status` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id=25 AND cat_index.visibility IN(2, 4) AND cat_index.category_id='474' AND cat_index.is_parent=1
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '1' AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0
 INNER JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_status` AS `at_stock_status` ON (at_stock_status.`product_id`=e.entity_id) AND (at_stock_status.stock_status = '1') AND (at_stock_status.website_id = '1') ORDER BY `price_index`.`min_price` asc, `price_index`.`min_price` asc, `price_index`.`min_price` asc LIMIT 8
```

This is the weird part. 
for **NO**  the `cat_index.category_id='86'`

for **YES** the `cat_index.category_id='474'`

My category ID is 474, NOT 86 . I have no any category with the value 86. All of the settings from admin panel is well done. I have products with attributes a,b,c and I have product which belongs to category 474. So it is not an administration settings. Can someone help me with this ? thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was xml configuration issue. The id 86 came from the xml settings:

```
<reference name="before_body_end">
            <block type="mana_filters/layer" name="mana_layer" as="mana_layer" before="-">
                <action method="setCategoryId"><category_id>86</category_id></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
```

I had to remove it and add this is xml code for showing the navigation layer:

```
<reference name="left">
            <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav1" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
        </reference>
```